# Row expand based on table td parentID and show child rows

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to solve one row expand and collapse according to the data. I'd like to expand the first row of the table  td assetsif it has child rows and also expand childrows as well if it has further sub child row  to the further it has now child rows.i want to show the data as in tree form as Chart of account which has five root parent and its child,subchilds,sub-sub-childs. i have tried in this away But failed to make it .what i am missing here ?link to code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-shadow-wsl8jm?file=/src/App.js:0-4385

**code**

```
import "./BalanceSheetTable.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaChevronDown, FaChevronRight } from "react-icons/fa"; // Import expand icons
//import data from "./data.js"
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    coaname: "Assets",
    debitAmount: 9028.081,
    creditAmount: 601.991,
    parentId: 1
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    coaname: "Liability",
    debitAmount: 10176.681,
    creditAmount: 24922.631,
    parentId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    coaname: "Income",
    debitAmount: 0,
    creditAmount: 207805,
    parentId: 3
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    coaname: "Current Assets",
    debitAmount: 1561.081,
    creditAmount: 64101.991,
    parentId: 1
  },

  {
    id: 5,
    coaname: "Non Current Assets",
    debitAmount: 7947,
    creditAmount: 0,
    parentId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    coaname: "Current Liability",
    debitAmount: 105.681,
    creditAmount: 2462.631,
    parentId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    coaname: "Non Current Liability",
    debitAmount: 1000,
    creditAmount: 90,
    parentId: 2
  },

  {
    id: 8,
    coaname: "Direct Income",
    debitAmount: 0,
    creditAmount: 207805,
    parentId: 3
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    coaname: "Sales",
    debitAmount: 0,
    creditAmount: 207805,
    parentId: 8
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    coaname: "Indirect Income",
    debitAmount: 0,
    creditAmount: 0,
    parentId: 3
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    coaname: "land",
    debitAmount: 111.081,
    creditAmount: 601.991,
    parentId: 4
  },{
    id: 12,
    coaname: "other assets",
    debitAmount: 0,
    creditAmount: 1500,
    parentId: 5
  }
];

function BalanceSheetTable({ data, parentId }) {
  const [expandedRows, setExpandedRows] = useState([]);

  const toggleRow = (id) => {
    setExpandedRows((prevExpandedRows) =>
      prevExpandedRows.includes(id)
        ? prevExpandedRows.filter((rowId) => rowId !== id)
        : [...prevExpandedRows, id]
    );
  };

  const getChildRows = (parentId) => {
    return data.filter((item) => item.parentId === parentId);
  };
  return (
    <table className="balance-sheet-table">
      <tbody>
        {data
          .filter((item) => item.parentId)
          .map((item) => (
            <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
              <tr className="parent-row">
                <td
                  className="parent-icon"
                  onClick={() =>
                    getChildRows(item.id).length > 0 && toggleRow(item.id)
                  }
                >
                  {getChildRows(item.id).length > 0 ? (
                    expandedRows.includes(item.id) ? (
                      <FaChevronDown />
                    ) : (
                      <FaChevronRight />
                    )
                  ) : (
                    <span className="empty-icon"></span>
                  )}
                </td>
                <td
                  onClick={() =>
                    getChildRows(item.id).length > 0 && toggleRow(item.id)
                  }
                >
                  {item.coaname}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {item.debitAmount.toLocaleString(undefined, {
                    minimumFractionDigits: 3
                  })}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {item.creditAmount.toLocaleString(undefined, {
                    minimumFractionDigits: 3
                  })}
                </td>
              </tr>
              {expandedRows.includes(item.id) &&
                getChildRows(item.id).length > 0 &&
                getChildRows(item.id).map((childItem) => (
                  <tr key={childItem.id} className="child-row">
                    <td className="child-icon"></td>
                    <td>{childItem.coaname}</td>
                    <td>
                      {childItem.debitAmount.toLocaleString(undefined, {
                        minimumFractionDigits: 3
                      })}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      {childItem.creditAmount.toLocaleString(undefined, {
                        minimumFractionDigits: 3
                      })}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BalanceSheetTable data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
  
**css**

.balance-sheet-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.parent-row,
.child-row {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.parent-row:hover,
.child-row:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.parent-row.expanded:hover,
.child-row.expanded:hover {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.parent-icon {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.child-icon {
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: transparent;
}

.expanded .parent-icon {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.parent-row.expanded .child-icon {
  color: #bbb;
}

.empty-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
}

.child-row .empty-icon {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.child-table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.child-row td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555;
}

.child-row td:first-child {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

/* Additional styling for expanded parent row */
.expanded .child-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.expanded .child-row td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.expanded .child-row td:first-child {
  padding-left: 120px;
}

/* Added styles for clickable rows */
.parent-row td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.child-row td {
  cursor: default;
}

/* Highlighting the clicked row */
.clicked-row {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```